# I'm so meta, try yourself with this!

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Long ago, where barrels ran ramped and the trees consumed the earth,
>   was a time of life and of love and of happiness.
>   (You put one and two together, and what do you get?)
>
> ---
>
> A long implementation of something so silly did we unearth,
>   beneath the meaning and nothing less.
>   (I'm sure you'll hear the words put together for it!↑<sup>1</sup>)
>   
>   Picture yourself at a table with friends;
>   what you hit to begin is something key,
>   for 'tis the moniker that he sends
>   for you to discover with me.
>   
>   I am on your left-hand side, as it may be
>   in each of three pictures on the glass.
>   My name is known, but only by he
>   who knows it not (but at this I'm just being an ***!).
>   
>   But as for me, **I** know me best,
>   writing as long as I can!
>   For all of my tomes, there'll be pain, lest
>   you enjoy to read. (Say my name, young man!).
>
> ---
>
> I am the one to offer a deal,
>   It is I to whom you will entrust your life
>   with the utmost zeal.
>   (But perhaps you gain instead, toil and strife.)
>   
>   And I am the lowest of the low, the incredible hulk
>   of cheating you into your fate.
>   If you set your eyes upon me, you'll sulk
>   into a fury to be described as irate.

Each paragraph yields a single word (or a hyphenated word), and each section (delineated by the `<hr>`s and quote borders) yields a number. The entire poem will yield one word. The rhymes are for flavour.

Your answer should include a clear explanation and justification of your answer.

May good luck and your mind be with you.

**HINT** 4 letters are involved.

**HINT 2** It can be found readily online.

Comment: So the three sections yield numbers consisting of one, four, and three words respectively, and these three numbers together yield a single word??

Comment: @randal'thor Ah, sorry. No: Each paragraph, on its own, will yield a word/hyphenated word. When looking at each section as a whole, you will be able to derive a number. When observing the entire poem, you will be able to again derive a word from it.

Comment: What about the first paragraph? A word that's also a number?

Comment: @randal'thor Why must it be a number?

Comment: Because it's also a section of its own, delineated by an <hr> and a quote border as you say!

Comment: @randal'thor Sorry, it's morning for me. Brain not working properly XD. I see the trouble. It yields a number, yes, but not a word.

Comment: The first paragraph makes me think of [Donkey Kong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donkey_Kong_(video_game))

Comment: i could only figure out 2 paragraphs (4th and 6th). Should i add the answer as progress?

Comment: @manshu Feel free!

Comment: @manshu As per your request, I will not post any more hints. Thanks for the bounty!

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ However this request is only valid till the bounty lasts...and after that may be you should consider adding another hint if the question is not solved

Comment: @manshu Yes, of course, Poor choice of wording on my part.

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ What does the arrow and 1 indicate? Is it the hint at the bottom? Also, what does 'barrel' mean in the first line? None of the dictionary meanings seem to make sense.

Comment: Is it related to 2012 movie somehow? *guessing*

Comment: @ABcDexter maybe you are right. coz OP already said in his earlier comments that it is a number.

Comment: Since the bounty period is long over, can you add any hints?

Comment: @question_asker Indeed.

Comment: @ABcDexter No, it is not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it xkcd? *Not sure about most of it, but this mostly fits.*

Clues with links:

> Long ago, where barrels ran ramped and the trees consumed the earth,
>   was a time of life and of love and of happiness. (You put one and two together, and what do you get?)

links:

> [The barrel comic was a series of comics with a guy floating in a barrel](http://xkcd.com/1/).  [Trees consumed the earth in one of the this comic.](https://xkcd.com/2/)

> There are some early comics referencing love, [notably this one](http://xkcd.com/17/) and [this one](http://xkcd.com/44/).

Another clue:

> Teacher. We trust him for knowledge.

Explanation:

> Randall and/or Conor has some weird ideas of "knowledge", but I guess this fits.

Not sure about some of the rest.  Will keep filling in.

Extra:

> xkcd is 4 letters and is a webcomic, so online.

Also,

> "I'm so meta" was one comic strip in xkcd.

Comment: Good job, spot on! Any ideas as to the rest of it?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ wait weren't you suspended? and no way.

Comment: Yes, but only on PPCG. And yes, way. :)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ I haven't really tried much on the other clues, but it was obvious once I read "4 letters" and "barrel". :P

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ also, Randall is not a very good source for life information.  Nerd sniping is just cruel.

Answer (score 2):

*If you can guess the answer. Then edit it. I have made this a community wiki*

Long ago, where barrels ran ramped and the trees consumed the earth,
was a time of life and of love and of happiness.
(You put one and two together, and what do you get?)

> 2012 movie. Barrels mean those ship at the end of the movie and tree means nature.

I am on your left-hand side, as it may be
in each of three pictures on the glass.
My name is known, but only by he
who knows it not

> Heart. It has 3 layers of wall. Couldn't figure out about 'My name is known'.

I am the one to offer a deal,
It is I to whom you will entrust your life
with the utmost zeal.
(But perhaps you gain instead, toil and strife.)

> Teacher. We trust him for knowledge.

Comment: Nice try, but not the answer I was looking for. :)

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ does it mean that none of them are correct? I have another choice for paragraph 4 i.e. S.E.

Comment: Sorry, but, yeah, none are correct.

Answer (score 1):

The likely answer to the fourth paragraph:

> Beret Guy

I'm mainly going off of the first two sentences, which reminded me of this image:

> [image]
>  Beret Guy is on the left. There are the three glasses in the middle.

The third sentence:

> *Technically*, given he is never given a "real" name, we give him a placeholder name. Hence, "Beret Guy."

But this answer isn't really satisfactory to me. It seems like a cop-out.

Final sentence: no idea. BUT...

> I am reminded of [this comic](https://www.xkcd.com/677/).
>  [image: Here, it's very clever]

A few other notes, starting with the up arrow.

> [Comic found here](https://xkcd.com/1208/)
>  [image: this]
>  Maybe the arrow should be ignored. It's a stretch, though.